# read() never finishes reading from curl request

Tags: c++, sockets, curl

I wrote a c++ program to listen for requests from a client application. The client application (which I did not write) sends the request and my server application receives and processes it. I can see that my server reads the whole request, but the client reports "Connection Refused". So I went to test it by sending some requests from the command line with curl, to see what it returns. The problem I'm having is that when I send the request with curl, my server application never finishes reading from the socket. It prints the line inside the while loop telling me how many bytes were read, but it hangs after that.

This is the simple code that reads the request from the socket. When I send the request from the real client, I see the "Request = " line printed on the screen, which means it finished reading the whole request. But when I send the request from curl, it hangs inside the loop and never finishes reading from the socket. I don't think the problem is in this code though.

```
char message_buffer [INPUT_BUFFER_SIZE + 1];
string request { "" };
int client_fd = client_file_descriptor.front ();
int message_len;

while ((message_len = read (client_fd, &message_buffer, INPUT_BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0)
{
    cout << "Read " << message_len << " bytes of request.\n";
    message_buffer [message_len] = '\0';
    request += message_buffer;
}

cout << "Request = " << request << "\n";
```

This is the curl command I am using from the command line. I don't use curl very often, so I suspect the problem might be in the way I'm calling it. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
curl -X POST -H "content-type:application/json" -H "content-length:50" "http://192.168.1.44:4444/" --data "{\"id\":111111,\"data\":{\"from\":\"USD\",\"to\":\"ETH,BTC\"}}"
```

Comment: curl is probably waiting for the response. So it will not close the socket and hence your `read` will just block.

Comment: You don't need `-H "content-length:..."`, `--data` will handle that for you. Your code is reading from the socket in an endless loop until `read()` fails. That is not the proper way to handle HTTP requests, you need to actually parse them to discover when they end. See [RFC 2616 Section 4.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.4) and [RFC 7230 Section 3.3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.3). I've posted [many examples of this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A65863+http+pseudo), but only from the client side, but server side logic will be very similar

Answer (score 1):

Don't (mis)calculate the content-length manually. Curl does that for you.

> It prints the line inside the while loop telling me how many bytes were read, but it hangs after that.

Specifically, it will something similar to

```
Read 179 bytes of request.
```

If you printed the request, you would find that you've received it in full:

```
std::cout << std::quoted(request) << "\n";
```

Prints

```
Read 179 bytes of request.
"POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8787
User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
Accept: */*
content-type:application/json
content-length:50

{\"id\":111111,\"data\":{\"from\":\"USD\",\"to\":\"ETH,BTC\"}}"
```

You need to either send a response or close the socket. I suggest you use a library (like libcurl or Boost Beast) to parse the HTTP request and detect when the request is complete.

### Demo Using Boost Beast

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c512bc83041ed55)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/http.hpp>
#include <boost/json.hpp>
#include <boost/json/src.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
namespace http = boost::beast::http;
namespace json = boost::json;
static constexpr size_t INPUT_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;

json::value read_request(tcp::socket& s)
{
    http::request<http::string_body>  request;

    boost::beast::flat_buffer buf(INPUT_BUFFER_SIZE);
    http::read(s, buf, request);

    return json::parse(request.body());
}

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_context ioc;
    tcp::acceptor acc(ioc, {{}, 8787}); 
    acc.listen();
    tcp::socket s = acc.accept();

    auto request = read_request(s);

    // leave server message
    request.as_object().emplace("Server", "Request Received OK");

    http::write(s,
                http::response<http::string_body>( //
                    http::status::ok, 11, serialize(request)));
}
```

Testing with

```
curl -X POST -H "content-type:application/json" "http://127.0.0.1:8787/" --data "{\"id\":111111,\"data\":{\"from\":\"USD\",\"to\":\"ETH,BTC\"}}"
```

Prints

```
{"id":111111,"data":{"from":"USD","to":"ETH,BTC"},"Server":"Request Received OK"}
```

Comment: Live demo http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c512bc83041ed55